# What are some concepts I can look into to aide in creating a 'compression funnel'(?) without the aide of a motor?

Tags: vacuum, aerodynamics, compressible-flow, drag

In short I'm designing a 'Humane fly swatter' for my University application into bachelor of Industrial Design.

The idea is to utilise the energy of swatting a fly to capture air through an intake, compress it and ejecting it at a higher velocity in turn drawing more air through the intake creating a slight vacuum, enough to draw the fly into a holding container.

To reiterate I'm not looking to create a big suction from the intake itself. Think of the swatter more as a butterfly net. You are capturing the fly into the funnel and from within the funnel the air velocity would have increased enough to suck the fly the remainder of the way into the holding container.

Simple visualisation of air being compressed and ejected through a formed funnel. 
[image: Essentially this effect]

So I'm wondering if anyone could at the bare minimum provide me with some keywords and concepts that I can use to help me research ways of achieving this and to use this information to inform my concept designs. My biggest issues isn't understanding the concepts but not having to vocabulary to be able to search for what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just make a butterfly net? Or do you mean that the collection vessel is solid? If so, hate to burst your bubble but [it's not going to work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4CQCNfe-KY&t=35s).

The name of the effect you're looking for is the [Venturi effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect), but it doesn't work quite how you seem to want it to from your description.

The mass of air that flows through the smaller diameter of your funnel has to go somewhere - where exactly is that? If it's a bottle, see the video I linked above - it's not going to work. If it's a mesh, then again, you've just made a more complicated butterfly net.

I hate to shoot an idea down without providing alternatives, but I don't see a way to make workable what you have described. I was motivated to get college degrees in engineering in part so I could critique my own designs, so hopefully you'll let this motivate you (to try something different and/or take some engineering classes) instead of getting discouraged.

Comment: Don't worry mate, I'm not discouraged nor am I opposed to learning engineering. That's neither here or there. The Venturi Effect has come up before. Sorry I didn't explain further, I didn't want to get too bogged down in the details. So yes, there will obviously be an outlet for the air. I imagine the container would be mesh with perhaps additional vents to flow air around the container if the mesh caused much resistance. Thanks for your help though. The Venturi Effect looks to be the shape I will model after.